# How to mock a method which relies on updating mutable objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a method which doesn't return a value. It instead accepts a list and modifies the members of this list. Obviously the list itself is mutable, as are its members.

EG: I want to mock this:

```
    void modifyRequests(List<MutableObject> requests);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, various mocking frameworks *do* provide ways of doing this (executing custom actions which use the parameters when a method is invoked) - but I would strongly consider *not* using mocking. Unless you really want to validate the *protocol* between your class-under-test and its collaborators, you should consider writing a *fake* instead of a mock. Then you can make the fake behave however you like - and typically (IME) you end up with simpler test code.

It's not always appropriate, and mocking certainly has its place - but over time I've found that a well-written fake can be worth its weight in gold, particularly if it's a dependency used by many classes.

Answer (score 2):

With [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer%28org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29) (I guess other mocking frameworks can do this as well):

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
      Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
      List<MutableObject> arg = args[0];
      MutableObject obj = arg.get(0);
      //...
      return null;
  }})
.when(mock).modifyRequests();
```

Ugly, don't you think? I strongly recommend extracting this anonymous inner class and naming it descriptively. I recommend even stronger to refactor your code and simply return the `List<MutableObject> requests` (or maybe return modified copy - passing objects to be modified is a bit clumsy).

Comment: +1 for refactoring the code; this is your tests tring you steer you away from a questionable design

Comment: I would prefer the return too.... I opted for the mutable concept since other methods will modify it too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are mocking that method, why does the code using that method need to know if the call to `modifyRequests()` changed anything?

In other words, you should be able to mock this method as a no-op and the code calling it should still function the same.

Otherwise, the code calling this method and the method itself are too tightly coupled.